# Is this compound noun compose of a group of many things plural or singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

In the following sentence, I'm not sure whether the noun should be considered plural or singular?

> A grid pattern of streets (Main, Elm, First) **are** shown.

Or:

> A grid pattern of streets (Main, Elm, First) **is** shown.

The `grid` is clearly singular, but `streets` is plural.  I'm thinking it should be singular because the grid contains the streets, but am not sure.  Which one is correct?

Comment: The general rule is to consider the subject with the qualifications removed -- "A grid pattern ... shown."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the compound *grid pattern* is clearly singular. There are some words in English which will take their number from the number of the noun within their complementary prepositional phrase, but *pattern* is not one of those nouns. Therefore, I would always use:

> A grid pattern of streets **is** shown.